# Dialogflow fulfillment URL issue

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am creating a voice-bot using dialogflow with google assistant. My client has provided his network access, which is not a private URL an IP instead. It is not SSL certified too. I will get two errors this time

1. Only public URLs are allowed and
2. You can use only https:// in fulfillment url when "Google Assistant" integration enabled

Any workaround for this? What are the other options I have? I can access clients API within his network only. So I cannot replace this IP address. Please advise how to proceed further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialogflow disable Google Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538487/dialogflow-disable-google-assistant)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IP address, as long as it is a public IP address. The machine doesn't need a DNS entry.

Actions on Google requires an HTTPS connection, however, using a valid certificate (ie - not self-signed). This is to protect your client and their users data.

One possible workaround is to look into a tunnel/proxy service such as [ngrok](http://ngrok.com). They provide a public HTTPS address that securely tunnels to an ngrok client you run on the same machine as the webhook fulfillment server. They have a free service that will change hostnames periodically, or you can subscribe to a commercial service which will give you a fixed name which you can use for the fulfillment URL.

Comment: ngrok is an easy way to get a secure(https) URL to your localhost server through any NAT or firewall. and you can set that URL as DialogFlow webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make URL https://.
you can try https://letsencrypt.org/