# Dialogflow disable Google Assistant

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to enable webhook fulfillment in my Dialogflow agent. However, whenever I go to input the URL of my service, I get an error saying `You can use only https:// in fulfillment url when "Google Assistant" integration enabled`. I have no interest in using the Google Assistant integration. So how can I disable it so that I can send webhooks to my http:// service?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm having problems duplicating this problem. Can you update your question to include a screen shot illustrating what you're experiencing?

Comment: It is all within the console, I have updated the question with an image.

Comment: I think it is expecting an `https` URL, which is secure. Can you try using a secure endpoint and see if the error goes away?

Comment: The error does go away with a secure endpoint. However I want to use an HTTP:// URL

Comment: For very good reasons http is not possible. You really need a secure transport. That's really easy to achieve with let's encrypt or nearly all web hosts. There simply is no way to make this work with http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue, if you don't need a secure connection via HTTPS here is how to remove Google Assistant integration and use a simple HTTP webhook fulfillment :

1. Export your DialogFlow bot :

[image: export]

2. Delete the bot:

[image]

3. Create a new empty bot and set a http webhook :

[image]

4. Import your previously exported bot :

[image]

5. Now you should have your previous bot working & released from Google Assistant

Comment: I ended up just getting an SSL cert for my URL but this is the solution to my question!

Comment: Yes getting SSL to work everywhere is the best practice 

Answer (score 0):

you could use ngrok to change your http://localhost:8080 to https and use it in fulfillment.